# Pass String along a res.redirect(path) call in Express Node project

Tags: node.js, express, connect, pug, response.redirect

I am using `res.redirect('/')` after a save operation in an Express project

How can I pass a certain string along with the redirect? I want to pass along some sort of notice to be displayed when the view is rendered. Many of my save/delete operations lead back to the main site or a certain subpage, so I would need a way to pass the string into the template where I can render it nicely.

I am using Coffee, Express and Jade for this project.

The function that catches that redirect is structured as such:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  // some stuff
```

Can i somehow add that string to the `req` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Express' [req.flash](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#req.flash%28%29), it was made for the purpose.

You can either iterate through your flashes in your template or use [express-messages](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages).

Comment: thank you VERY much, i will look into that. i remember a flash object from my experiments with rails.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably quite late to answer this but,

I think what you can do is:

```
res.redirect("/?variable1=I+am+a+programmer&variable2=2345")
```

and then use it on your `/` route through `req.query.variable1` and `req.query.variable2`